# Categorical or Continuous

Tags: r, machine-learning

I am trying to do machine learning using CART and linear/logistic regression using R, however, I faced a problem.

The variable I am predicting is insurance premium, and in my dataset, I have 988 rows.

I did a:

```
length(unique(CBA$Premium))
```

and found that it only returns 24 unique values.

Should I treat this variable as categorical or leave it as continuous?

Comment: Im looking at regression!

Comment: If you treat it as categorical, then you lose ordering information. As a numeric, the model "understands" that 1 < 2 < 3 < 4 ....As a categorical variable, that information is lost.

Answer (score 1):

Normally I would considere insurance premium as a continuous variable. That being said and given that you only have 24 unique values, you might want to investigate why there are only 24 unique values. There might be a reason for that. E.g you start with a minimum premium and then have premium add-ons for additional features, like an age premium if someone is below / above a certain age or a premium because you want to insure a second item etc. etc.

You need to talk to the actuaries responsible for this product and also check how the system decides how a premium is set when someone asks for an insurence quote.